# Bulk insert images as file objects

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, pictures

I'm writing a report where a lot of evidence is summarised in text and supported by hundreds of accompanying screenshots which don't necessarily need to be seen but need to be available as an option.

So, to achieve this, I want to bulk insert / embed the image files **as objects**, not as pictures, in the same way that Word does by default for HTML, PDF, etc files. This way, if a user wants to see the file then they can simply double-click on them to open them in their default apps.

Basically, I want the end result to look like this:
[image]

However, I can't see a way of doing this automatically:

- `Insert` tab → `Text` group → `Object` button → `Create from File` tab doesn't allow the selection of multiple files.
- Copy-and-pasting normally inserts them as pictures.
- Copy-and-pasting specially (CTRL + ALT + V) → `Paste` → second / bottom `Files` → `Display as icon` inserts them as pictures, even though it's not supposed to.

I can do so manually but it's very time-consuming because each must be done individually, Word never remembers the last path used, Word never remembers the last icon chosen, etc.

Comment: Would it not be better to zip them up and attach a single zip? And then call the files out from the text? i.e. "see image abc_123"

Comment: @spikey_richie That's what we're doing currently but it has downsides. For example, the information must be encrypted and Windows Explorer can't decrypt password-protected ZIP files so then you have to use something like free like 7-Zip but that requires the recipients to be technical and have permission to install apps, etc. Also, I literally have 254 supporting documents of various file types for this report so manually referencing them would be too much work.

Comment: OK, fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the following VBA code which does what I want:

```
Public lastPath As String

Sub InsertFolderContents()
    ' This mode is used to pick a folder and have all files inserted
    Dim counter_filesInserted As Integer
    counter_filesInserted = 1 ' Even though no files have been inserted yet, it's easier to not have to think in 0-based indexes

    Dim fileExplorer As FileDialog
    Dim folder_Path As String

    Set fileExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fileExplorer
        .InitialFileName = lastPath

        If .Show = -1 Then ' ".Show" actually causes the dialogue to open
            folder_Path = .SelectedItems.Item(1) & Application.PathSeparator ' "Application.PathSeparator" is required to be appended otherwise the later concatenated path is invalid
            lastPath = folder_Path
        Else
            folder_Path = "NONE"
        End If
    End With

    Dim Files As String
    Files = Dir(folder_Path)

    ' For some reason, calling InsertFiles from within Do While completely breaks "Files = Dir" so need to build array of files THEN loop through them to call InsertFiles

    Dim counter_fileList As Integer

    Dim DirectoryListArray() As String
    ReDim DirectoryListArray(1000)

    Do While Files <> ""
        DirectoryListArray(counter_fileList) = Files
        Files = Dir
        counter_fileList = counter_fileList + 1
    Loop

    ReDim Preserve DirectoryListArray(counter_fileList - 1)

    For counter_fileList = 0 To UBound(DirectoryListArray)
        Dim file_Name_Original As String
        file_Name_Original = DirectoryListArray(counter_fileList)
        Dim file_Path As String
        file_Path = folder_Path & file_Name_Original

        InsertFiles file_Path, counter_filesInserted
    Next counter_fileList
End Sub


Sub InsertMultipleFiles()
    ' This mode is used to pick specific files to have inserted

    Dim counter_filesInserted As Integer
    counter_filesInserted = 1 ' Even though no files have been inserted yet, it's easier to not have to think in 0-based indexes

    Dim fileExplorer As FileDialog
    Dim folder_Path As String

    Set fileExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fileExplorer
        .InitialFileName = lastPath
        .AllowMultiSelect = True

        If .Show = -1 Then ' ".Show" actually causes the dialogue to open
            folder_Path = Left(.SelectedItems.Item(1), InStrRev(.SelectedItems.Item(1), "\"))
            lastPath = folder_Path
        Else
            folder_Path = "NONE"
        End If

        Dim file_Path As Variant
        For Each file_Path In .SelectedItems
            InsertFiles file_Path, counter_filesInserted
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function InsertFiles(file_Path, counter_filesInserted)
    Dim file_Name_Original As String
    Dim file_Ext As String
    Dim file_Inserted As Boolean
    Dim regex As Object

    file_Name_Original = Dir(file_Path)

    file_Ext = Right(file_Path, Len(file_Path) - InStrRev(file_Path, "."))

    file_Inserted = False

    ' My report standalone files are named "<section number> <section title> - " so this regex strips those out for readability but doesn't affect files that aren't named that way
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Pattern = "\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}(.\d{1,2})?[\w\s]+ - "
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Global = True
    file_Name_Shortened = regex.Replace(file_Name_Original, "")

    ' The IconIndex number is literally just what number icon is inside that file -1 (as it's a 0-based index). An easy way to determine this is to use Word's "Change icon" function.

    If file_Ext = "png" Or file_Ext = "jpg" Then
        Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
        FileName:=file_Path, _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
        IconFileName:="C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", _
        IconIndex:=13, _
        IconLabel:=file_Name_Shortened

        file_Inserted = True
    ElseIf file_Ext = "html" Then
        Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
        FileName:=file_Path, _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
        IconFileName:="C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", _
        IconIndex:=1, _
        IconLabel:=file_Name_Shortened

        file_Inserted = True
    ElseIf file_Ext = "pdf" Then
        Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
        FileName:=file_Path, _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
        IconFileName:="C:\Windows\Installer\{AC76BA86-7AD7-1033-7B44-AC0F074E4100}\PDFFile_8.ico", _
        IconIndex:=1, _
        IconLabel:=file_Name_Shortened

        file_Inserted = True
    ElseIf file_Ext = "csv" Or file_Ext Like "xls*" Then
        Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
        FileName:=file_Path, _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
        IconFileName:="C:\Windows\Installer\{90160000-000F-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe", _
        IconIndex:=1, _
        IconLabel:=file_Name_Shortened

        file_Inserted = True
    ElseIf file_Ext Like "doc*" Then
        Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
        FileName:=file_Path, _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
        IconFileName:="C:\Windows\Installer\{90160000-000F-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\wordicon.exe", _
        IconIndex:=13, _
        IconLabel:=file_Name_Shortened

        file_Inserted = True
    End If

    If file_Inserted = True Then
        ' Inserted file objects look untidy without a tab for space between them but you have to not do this every 4th otherwise it looks weird.
        If (counter_filesInserted Mod 4) <> 0 Or counter_filesInserted = 0 Then
                Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
        End If

        counter_filesInserted = counter_filesInserted + 1
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

A nice side effect of this is that files are ordered alphabetically whereas they aren't if you bulk import using the normal methods.